# ButtonClikListner event is not being fired in Custom_dialogue | Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In one of my activity `Surah.java` , i am using custom_dialogue with `custom_dialog.xml` to prompt the user. That dialogue box contains two buttons on it. I just want to handle the `click events` for both of buttons. I have written the handlers in `custom_dialog.java` but that made no difference.

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/ok" 
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="OK" />
<Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```

**custom_dialog.java**

```
package com.quran.peacequran;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class custom_dialog extends Activity {


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);


         Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No stores", 5000).show();
                }
            }); 

    }

}
```

**Surah.java**

```
package com.quran.peacequran;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Surah extends Fragment {

....
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), generateData());

    // 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int index, long arg3) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"thul thuk!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                   dialog.setTitle("BookMark Surah?");
                   dialog.show();  
               return false;
                    }
        });
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use the below code to get the onclick in Surah.java inside the  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(....... after you create the dialog object


dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it works", 2000).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: "such method does not exist"